# How to update the state of one particular element while using map function

Tags: reactjs

i need a solution for this situations which i'm going to explain.

**Scenario:**

1- i have a map and on `onMoveEnd` i update the location of the `state`;

2- and i have a list which i'm looping through with `.map` and render `SampleComponent`.

3- then pass the location into `SampleComponent`;

4- my `SampleComponent` is in the `Expansion Panel` and i toggle the Expansion Panel with `isExpanded` to handle open and close actions;

**problem:**

each time location updated, it gets updated in all `SampleComponent` i looping through.
but i need to update it only in `SampleComponent` which have a `isExpanded = true`, and not all of them.

any solution ?

Comment: Any code? Any Examples? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: actually the whole code is about to 400 lines of code but i try to create sandbox.
i figured it needs a code.

Comment: You don't need to show the actual code, try making a minimal, producible example of the **problem** - which is how to handle multiple states

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually i used `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps` to handle this situation before.

but `UNSAFE_` looks ugly to me so i do this:

in my `SampleComponent` i used

```
   const [location, setlocation] = useState({ title: '' });
   useEffect(() => {
        if (props.isExpanded) {
            setlocation(props.location);
        }
    }, [props.location.title]);
```

first i listen to location changes when it's time to update the location i checked the `isExpanded` to make sure my panel is open then i apply the changes with `setlocation(props.location)`.
and change the `props.location` into local `location`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `React.memo` for functional component or `shouldComponentUpdate` for components based on classes. They should be return false or true on depend need component update. For your case:

```
function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
   // Component will not re-render if isExpanded is true
   return nextProps.isExpanded
}

export default React.memo(SampleComponent, areEqual)
```

For more information: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo